# PhpWord: cannot set Cell style from Style object

Tags: php, phpword

I am manipulating a Word document I got from users. I need to make copies of a table, or maybe of its containing sections; but I cannot convert it into a template, because I have also to use PhpWord methods. So I tried to write a method to clone an element:

```
    private function cloneWordElement(&$destContainer, &$element) {
        $newel = null ;
        if ($element instanceof Table) {
            $newel = $destContainer->addTable($element->getStyle()) ;
            foreach ($element->getRows() as $srcRow)
                $this->cloneWordElement($newel, $srcRow) ;
        }
        else if ($element instanceof Row) {
            $newel = $destContainer->addRow($element->getHeight(), $element->getStyle()) ;
            foreach ($element->getCells( )as $srcCell)
                $this->cloneWordElement($newel, $srcCell) ;
        }
        else if ($element instanceof Cell)
            $newel = $destContainer->addCell($element->getWidth(), $element->getStyle()) ;
        else if ($element instanceof TextRun)
            $newel = $destContainer->addTextRun($element->getParagraphStyle()) ;
        else if ($element instanceof Text)
            $newel = $destContainer->addText($element->getText(), $element->getFontStyle(),
                $element->getParagraphStyle()) ;
        else if ($element instanceof TextBreak)
            $newel = $destContainer->addTextBreak(1, $element->getFontStyle(),
                $element->getParagraphStyle()) ;
        else
            $this->log->debug("Found a " . get_class($element)) ;

        if ($element instanceof AbstractContainer)
            foreach ($element->getElements() as $srcSubel)
                $this->cloneWordElement($newel, $srcSubel) ;

        return $newel ;
    }
```

The final `else` is there to help me catch new types of `Element`, should they appear – so far this is enough for my purposes. Well, *almost* enough: I noticed that `Cell` style is not correctly copied, so I investigated and I found out that in the constructor its style is set in this way:

```
$this->style = $this->setNewStyle(new CellStyle(), $style, true);
```

and `setNewStyle()` comes from `AbstractElement`:

```
    protected function setNewStyle($styleObject, $styleValue = null, $returnObject = false)
    {
        if (null !== $styleValue && is_array($styleValue)) {
            $styleObject->setStyleByArray($styleValue);
            $style = $styleObject;
        } else {
            $style = $returnObject ? $styleObject : $styleValue;
        }

        return $style;
    }
```

So, `$style` cannot be a `Style\Cell`, it has to be an array. This is rather frustrating, because `setNewStyle()` *would* allow me to use the third parameter to set the style to my value, but I cannot change it in the constructor. And I cannot extend `Cell` because I cannot create it explicitely, it will be created for me by `addCell()`.

So I ended up setting the style explicitely:

```
        else if ($element instanceof Cell) {
            $style = $element->getStyle() ;
            $newel = $destContainer->addCell($element->getWidth(), [
                'bgColor' => $style->getBgColor(),
                'vAlign' => $style->getVAlign(),
                'unit' => $style->getUnit(),
                'borderStyle' => $style->getBorderStyle(),
            ]) ;
        }
```

In this case I could get by with just four settings, but this may easily get overwhelming.

Fortunately `Text` and `TextRun` do not present this drawback, their styles are easily copied from origin to destination; that is, in fact, the reason why I made this error, I made my way up from text to cells to tables and I didn't realize that what worked for the first elements stopped working for others.

I wonder if there is a readon for this inconsistency, and if there is hope that it may get fixed on upcoming versions? I am using phpword 1.1.0, as obtained by default from composer.

Comment: This sounds like a question for the developers, and not something that this community can answer